# Create emulator with API level 32 in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I created an emulator but it doesn't work. I selected `pixel 3a xl` phone and I selected `Android API 32 (Google play)` with `x86-64 ABI`. It gets timed out when I run the emulator and also i see the below messages in logcat. I need to make an emulator for testing my app on andorid 12 device. Please help me if you know.

> 2022-01-29
> 4:59 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

```
4:59 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

 4:59 PM    Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:59 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:59 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

4:59 PM Emulator: F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86- 20140702\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

4:59 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:59 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:59 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Pixel 2` device?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I use 'Pixel 2' device, I get the same errors. I select different devices but for every of them, I get the same errors.

Comment: do other api work?